# Struggling to get .fadeIn jQuery to work on a homepage image transition script

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm unsure if fadeIn is even the right transition (newbie), but I'm basically trying to have a crossfade between homepage images that change every 3 seconds. The changing is working successfully, but I don't know how to get them to fade. Currently there is just an abrupt switch. Here is my code:

```
    var images = ["image-link1", "image-link2"];
$(function () {
    var i = 0;
    document.getElementById("homeImage").src = images[i];
    setInterval(function () {
        if (i == images.length) {
            i = 0;
        }
        else { 
            document.getElementById("homeImage").src = images[i];
            $(this).fadeIn("slow");
            i++;
        }
    }, 3000);
});
```

I'm using ASP.NET MVC. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to fade out before that,  you can add `fadeOut` before changing the elememt's background and then add `fadeIn` when the background has changed

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That didn't work unfortunately. Code looks like this now:

Comment: else { 
            $(this).fadeOut("slow");
            document.getElementById("homeImage").src = images[i];
            $(this).fadeIn("slow");
            i++;

Comment: Can you add a jsFiddle so I can see it live

Comment: What is jsFiddle?

Answer (score 0):

The steps will be

1. Show an image.
2. Fade out the current image.
3. After finished fading out, change the url to a new image.
4. Fade in to show the new image.

Working solution:

```html
 $(function () {
    var i = 0;
    document.getElementById("homeImage").src = images[i];
    setInterval(function () {
        if (i == images.length - 1) {
            i = 0;
        }
        else { 
            $('#homeImage').fadeOut("slow", function() {
                document.getElementById("homeImage").src = images[i];
                $('#homeImage').fadeIn("slow");
            });
            i++;
        }
    }, 3000);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. However, now my navigation bar flashes while the fading is happening. Add, considering it's in a completely different section to my homepage image.

Comment: I added my layout.cshtml code below. I've also noticed that after the first iteration the first image in the list of URLs is excluded from the slideshow :/

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - Williams Marketing Studio</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/newstyle.css">
    @RenderSection("metatags", required: false)
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <nav>
            <div class="nav-bar">
                <span><a href="/Home/Index"><img src="~/Content/Images/nav-image.png" class="img-nav" title="Williams Marketing Studio" aria-label="Company Logo" /></a></span>
                <ul class="nav-links">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Services", "Index", "Services")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Categories", "Index", "Categories")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                </ul>
                @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Services", FormMethod.Get, new { @class = "navbar-form navbar-left" }))
                {
                    <div class="flex-row">
                        @Html.TextBox("Search", null, new { @class = "form-input", @placeHolder = "Search Services" })
                        <button type="submit" class="button">Search</button>
                    </div>
                }
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <section>
        <div>
            <p><img id="homeImage" src="~/Content/Images/home-image2.jpg" class="header-image" padding="0px" title="Homepage Image" aria-label="Colourful Laptop Screen"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="container body-content">
            @RenderBody()
            <hr />
    </section>
    <footer>
        <div class="footer">
            <section class="footer-column">
                Copyright &copy;@DateTime.Now.Year<br>
                <a href="mailto:meljwilliams@yahoo.com" title="Email Us">Williams Marketing Studio</a>
                <a href="https://validator.w3.org/docs/users.html#Calling" title="HTML Validator" style="color: #87edaa;">W3C Validator API</a>
                <a href="https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/manual.html" title="CSS Validator" style="color: #87edaa;">CSS Validator</a>
            </section>
            <section class="footer-column">
                <span><a href="/Home/Index" title="HOME" aria-label="HOME"><img src="~/Content/Images/nav-image.png" alt="footer logo" height="100px"></a></span>
            </section>
            <section class="footer-column">
                <ul class="footer-links">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Services", "Index", "Services")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Categories", "Index", "Categories")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                </ul>
            </section>
        </div>
    </footer>
    <!--<footer>
        <address>
            Written by <a href="mailto:meljwilliams@yahoo.com">Williams Marketing Studio</a><br>
        </address>
        <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year </p>
    </footer>-->
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
        </html>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.